# Add some new data into an Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I got an Array like this:

```
array('Testing'=>array(
'topic'=>$data['Testing']['topic'], 
'content'=>$data['Testing']'content'])
             );
```

Now I have got some new data to add into the Array shown aboved,
how can I do it so that the new Array will look like this:

```
array('Testing'=>array(
'topic'=>$data['Testing']['topic'], 
'content'=>$data['Testing']['content']),
'new'=>$data['Testing']['new'])
                 );
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the same way that you can access arrays values by key, you can set by key, as well.

```
<?php
$array = array('foo' => array('bar' => 'baz'));
$array['foo']['spam'] = 'eggs';
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'foo' => 
  array (
    'bar' => 'baz',
    'spam' => 'eggs',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$testing = array(
   'Testing' => array(
      'topic' => 'topic', 
      'content' => 'content'
   )
);

$newTesting = array(
   'Testing' => array(
      'new' => 'new'
   )
);

$testing = array_merge_recursive($testing, $newTesting);
```

will output

```
array (
  'Testing' => array (
    'topic' => 'topic',
    'content' => 'content',
    'new' => 'new',
  ),
)
```

**NOTE :** if you want to override something, using this method will not work. For example, taking the same initial `$testing` array, if you have :

```
$newTesting = array(
   'Testing' => array(
      'content' => 'new content',
      'new' => 'new'
   )
);

$testing = array_merge_recursive($testing, $newTesting);
```

Then the output will be :

```
array (
  'Testing' => array (
    'topic' => 'topic',
    'content' => array (
      0 => 'content',
      1 => 'content-override',
    ),
    'new' => 'new',
  ),
)
```

But if this is a desired behavior, then you got it!

**EDIT** : take a look here to if array_merge_recursive should replace instead of adding new elements for the same key : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#93905